# Asynchronous message queue for Django?

Tags: python, django, zeromq

I have a program that currently collects data from a server and sends it to a bottle microframework server using zeromq which then updates the data on a webpage using a websocket.

I want to be able to do this using Django using a lightweight asynchronous mq. Any alternatives to zmq that has supported documentation on how to implement it? I'm aware django-ztask exists but it's hard to find much documentation on how to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: you could probably use a redis pub/sub channel. Also, here's some advice from Armin Ronacher (the author of Flask). He says to keep web sockets separate from the rest of your stack. http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/9/24/websockets-101/